# Use gsap ScrollTrigger with React useRef() and Typescript - types not matching

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gsap

So I have a simple React Component and want to animate it with GreenSock ScrollTrigger plugin. Unfortunatelly in this project I use Typescript and there is a types mismatch. The Code:

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect}  from "react";
import gsap from 'gsap'
import ScrollTrigger from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Component() {

    const content = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
        gsap.from(content.current, {opacity: 0, y: 100, duration: 1, scrollTrigger:content.current})
    },[])

    return (
        <Container ref={content}>
          {..some content}
        </Container>
    )
}
const Container = styled.div`
  //styles here
`
```

Apparently scrollTriger accepts only types: 'string | Element | undefined'
so I end up with error:

```
Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'string | Element | undefined'.
[1]   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Element | undefined'.
```

Without Typescript this code works.

I looked up gsap forum, but found nothing, very little resources on TS.

Any ideas how could I work it around?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got that solved easier than I thought. Because type 'null' was incompatibile with 'string | Element | undefined', the assertion operator "!" solved the issue.

Now instead of:

```
// bad
gsap.from(content.current, {opacity: 0, y: 100, duration: 1, scrollTrigger:content.current})
```

I've got:

```
// good
gsap.from(content.current!, {opacity: 0, y: 100, duration: 1, scrollTrigger:content.current!})
```

Comment: It's probably better to check to see if it's not null before you create the tween to avoid the work of creating it.